# how can I draw pie chart on Heatmap?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly-python, ipywidgets

I am using plotly in jupyter notebook for analyzing data. I have a heatmap plot and would like to project some data as a pie chart on the map. So basically, in each color cell on the hitmap I would like to draw piechart like in example below.

[image]

Is there any way to do it? For example somthing similar to add_trace function

Answer (score 0):

My choise was to create Pie chart from plotly, convert to image and add as an iamge om the layer. That is a little bit take time to compute...